# loading the data to Corpus from 2 directories in R

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I am using tm package in R to perform Text Mining over a data set whose structure is as follows:

There is a directory group_Data which contains 2 different directories with name B and C. Now directory B contains documents and directory C also contains documents.

I know the way to load the data of directory B and C individually by creating 2 Corpus:

```
library(tm)
pathToB = "group_Data/B"
pathToC = "group_Data/C"

bCorpus = Corpus(DirSource(pathToB), 
                readerControl = list(reader = readPlain))
cCorpus = Corpus(DirSource(pathToC), 
                readerControl = list(reader = readPlain))
length(bCorpus)
length(cCorpus)
```

But I need to load the data from B and C into a single Corpus. 
This is what I tried:

```
pathToBAndC = "group_Data"
corpusBC = Corpus(DirSource(pathToBAndC), 
                readerControl = list(reader = readPlain))
```

On running the length command as mentioned below, it gives 0

```
length(corpusBC)
```

Can someone point out if I am missing out an option inside Corpus method that could do this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either combine corpuses with

```
corpusBC <- c(bCorpus, cCorpus)
```

Or according to the documentation for `?DirSource`you can pass in a vector of paths

```
corpusBC <- Corpus(DirSource(c(pathToB, pathToC)), 
    readerControl = list(reader = readPlain))
```